# Netlogo Benchmarking

Tags: installation, benchmarking, netlogo

I'm a little rusty on running Netlogo from commandline and have never used the benchmarking feature before. It seems promising. =)

I'm totally at the beginning, because it seems NetLogo 6.0 may be a bit different than 5.*.

I'm trying to get the benchmarking suite to run: https://github.com/NetLogo/NetLogo/wiki/Benchmarking

For now, I downloaded some of the files from http://ccl.northwestern.edu/netlogo/models/models/test/benchmarks/

and created 2 directories in my NetLogo 6.0 directory

> NetLogo 6.0/models/tests

and

> NetLogo 6.0/models/benchmarks

and put the files from http://ccl.northwestern.edu/netlogo/models/models/test/benchmarks/ into my benchmarks directory.

On the website, it says to run `./sbt` and then `run-main org.nlogo.headless.HeadlessBenchmarker Bureaucrats` However, I'm being n00bish and don't have the command ./sbt setup. I saw that this was a general extension installer command thing online, but wasn't sure what to do with it...Sorry. So my question now is, what do I do next in order for me to get this up and running?

From the documentation side of things, I think it may need to be cleared up that there should be a file in `/models/test/benchmarks/` named `"Bureaucrats Benchmark.nlogo"` I didn't realize the driver appends `" Benchmark.nlogo"` to the name provided. It may be useful to say to provide the `<name>` to the org.nlogo.headless.HeadlessBenchmarker if the file is called `"<name> Benchmark.nlogo"`

I didn't get to it yet, but is there any way for us to call all the benchmarks in the benchmarks directory? There was a reference to it in the docs, but I didn't see any command.

Let me know what you think and any help is appreciated!

Edit: After downloading the repo from git, as Bryan suggested, I ran the ./sbt and got the following error.

> [error] (run-main-0) java.lang.ClassNotFoundException:
>   org.nlogo.headless.HeadlessBenchmarker
>   java.lang.ClassNotFoundException:
>   org.nlogo.headless.HeadlessBenchmarker    at
>   java.lang.ClassLoader.findClass(ClassLoader.java:530)     at
>   java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:424) [trace] Stack
>   trace suppressed: run last root/compile:runMain for the full output.
>   java.lang.RuntimeException: Nonzero exit code: 1  at
>   scala.sys.package$.error(package.scala:27) [trace] Stack trace
>   suppressed: run last root/compile:runMain for the full output. [error]
>   (root/compile:runMain) Nonzero exit code: 1 [error] Total time: 2 s,
>   completed Apr 10, 2017 2:16:21 PM

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`./sbt` is included in the NetLogo repository. It's [this](https://github.com/NetLogo/NetLogo/blob/hexy/sbt) file. Running that will install sbt (and scala) itself, if need be. Make sure you're inside the root directory of the NetLogo repository when you run it.

Edit:

Wait, to clarify, are you trying to benchmark your own models or NetLogo itself?

If NetLogo itself (which is what https://github.com/NetLogo/NetLogo/wiki/Benchmarking is talking about), you need to checkout the NetLogo repository from github: https://github.com/NetLogo/NetLogo . The only reason you'd probably want to be doing this is if you're planning on contributing to core NetLogo code or are working on an extension or something.

For just benchmarking your own models, you don't want to do any of that. Typically, it's better to just benchmark from within the NetLogo program, not at the command line. The simplest way of benchmarking is doing things like this:

```
setup reset-timer repeat 1000 [ go ] print timer
```

which will tell you how long it takes for your model to do 1000 ticks. So, run that a couple times , modify your model, and then run it a couple more times, and that will give you sense of how your changes affected performance.

For more in depth benchmarking and profiling, use the [profiler](https://ccl.northwestern.edu/netlogo/docs/profiler.html) extension. That will break your program down, telling you how long each procedure is taking and so forth.

Comment: I was planning on benchmarking some of the primitives compared against some alternative implementations on the Netlogo side of things. For example, in-radius pulls out a square and filters through it. There's more algorithms existing that can compute the result in pi * r^2 vs Netlogo's 4r^2. I thought that by using your code provided (setup a timer) may not be sufficient for JVM's---typically, you have a warm-up phase and throw away the initial few results. Shouldn't I do this? If so, I didn't want to have to be careful about how I designed the benchmark to test the performance. Thoughts?

Comment: I do want to look at the low level implementations and some high-level concepts. I gave the in-radius example, but I'd also be comparing using A* vs IDA* for searching in a grid for some examples.

Comment: Using the benchmarking framework for this is a good idea, in my opinion, for the reasons you state. Proper benchmarking is hard and our benchmarking code does a better job of it than `timer` will. Sadly, though, our benchmarking framework predates the existence of JMH; ideally it would be rewritten to be JMH-based.

Comment: So, is the suggested answer of using timer acceptable for some models? If so, what kind of models I noticed Grimm published a paper regarding the timer and profiler extension. My biggest complaint was that their benchmarks violated the traditional JVM benchmarking principals. So, under which circumstances is the timer method considered good enough? For reference on the paper, see http://jasss.soc.surrey.ac.uk/20/1/3.html .

Comment: @SethTisue , Bryan,I got an issue while trying to run the benchmark. I downloaded the repository and ran ./sbt in the repo. I've updated my question to contain the results. Any idea on why I'm getting this error with the benchmarker?

Comment: "under which circumstances is the timer method considered good enough" — well, that depends on context, but if something takes an hour to run, you can time it with a kitchen timer, and if it takes a week to run, you can time it with a sundial.

Comment: @SethTisue Good point. I'll add a sun dial extension to the github. On a side note, any idea why the ClassNotFound exception is occurring?

Answer (score 2):

I've updated the wiki page with the current correct command. (I changed `run-main` to `headless/runMain`.)

> is there any way for us to call all the benchmarks in the benchmarks directory?

I think it does that if you don't pass a benchmark name...? Worth a try. (If you figure it out, please update the wiki page.)

Comment: I accepted @bryan's answer because he pointed me to the ./sbt. I awarded you the bounty because you provided the command to get the benchmark working. I'll play around with things and update where needed. Thanks!

Comment: One more thing, could you explain why the results:
 "[info] 1/2 (mean=4.156, stddev=0.000)
[info] 4/340 (mean=4.040, stddev=0.096)". On each line, this is the accumulated mean and standard deviation of all the runs and not just for the last 10 seconds?

Comment: Yes, accumulated. The logic is in https://github.com/NetLogo/NetLogo/blob/hexy/netlogo-headless/src/main/workspace/Benchmarker.scala . "Stop when we are 98% confident that we're within 0.3% of the truth"